# Outputting Values of a Variable to Text File

Tags: python, spi

I am pretty new to python and need to output values read in by an SPI to a text file. I have a function to create the text file, and one to read the SPI but I am not sure how to get these two to interact with each other. I am familiar with the concept of "friends" in OOP but not how python treats separate functions in terms of how to create visibility. What I need is to pass the returned value of my SPI function to the create text function so that it can be stored.

```
def timeStamp(fname, fmt = '%Y%m%d--%H%M%S_{fname}'):                       
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname = fname)

with open (timeStamp('SPI_Inputs'), 'w') as output:     
        output.write('this needs to be adc output')

def readadc(adcnum):
    if adcnum > 7 or adcnum < 0:
        return -1
    r = spi.xfer2([1,8 + adcnum << 4,0])
    adcout = ((r[1] & 3) << 8) + r[2]
    return adcout   #this needs to be put into text file

while True:
    ADC_Val = int(round(readadc(0)/10.24))
    print "Input = ", ADC_Val
    count = count +1
    time.sleep (0.2)

    timeStamp(readadc))
```

Comment: def timeSTamp(fname, fmt = '%Y%m%d--%H%M%S_{fname}'):      #formats filename
 return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname = fname)
 
with open (timeStamp('SPI_Inputs'), 'w') as output:
 
  output.write('this needs to be adc output')

def readadc (adcnum) :

 if adcnum > 7 or adcnum < 0:
  return -1
 r = spi.xfer2([1,8 + adcnum << 4,0])
 adcout = ((r[1] & 3) << 8) + r[2]
 return adcout          #this neds to be put ionto text file
 
while True:

 ADC_Val = int(round(readadc(0)/10.24))
 print "Input = ", ADC_Val
 count = count +1
 time.sleep (0.2) 
timeStamp(readadc))

Comment: Please add the code to the question, take care of formatting, indentation etc

Comment: The code is added now, sorry didn't mean to post the code unformatted

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're trying to do is the following:

```
def timeStamp(fname, fmt = '%Y%m%d--%H%M%S_{fname}'):                       
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname = fname)

def write_to_file(str):
    with open (timeStamp('SPI_Inputs'), 'w') as output:     
        output.write(str)

def readadc(adcnum):
    if adcnum > 7 or adcnum < 0:
        return -1
    r = spi.xfer2([1,8 + adcnum << 4,0])
    adcout = ((r[1] & 3) << 8) + r[2]
    return adcout   #this needs to be put into text file

while True:
    ADC_Val = int(round(readadc(0)/10.24))
    write_to_file(ADC_Val)
    print "Input = ", ADC_Val
    time.sleep (0.2)
    print timeStamp(readadc))
```

Comment: This hasnt worked for me, the ADC value has to be written to the file in the while loop OK though this method gives the error expected a character buffer object, though the ADC input is obviously a string

Comment: I have changed the write to adc function so that it takes in an integer. meaning it wil now accept ADCVal, however the code actually creates a new text file for each value rather than putting them in to one.

Comment: @user3701065 change the lines that opens the file to use `'a'` instead of `'w'` (append mode instead of write mode): `open (timeStamp('SPI_Inputs'), 'a')`

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't really fix the problem. I think I need to restructure the while loop so that it writes to the text file, sleeps then write to the text file again, i don't really need the 'print' line other than to see that the code is working.

Comment: If you want to write to the same file you might as well open it in the beginning and keep it open all the time instead of re-opening it again and again. You can also try to use `file.close()` when you're done writing

Comment: Yeah, the code suggested does read in the values and place them in a file, but creates a different file to place them in each time as then time has changed between samples.  I am trying to figure out how to use the loop to place the latesst sample in the one file

Comment: OK so removing timeStamp from the write_to_file function means that ll inputs are now being placed into the file. What I now want to is call the timeStamp once so that my files have the desired naming convention, without then creating a new file every time the code loops through